# Logic statement within a loop for ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

What would be the logic statement to notify the user that they purchased the same product within the last 90 days?

```
   SQL = "SELECT id, PurchaseDate, ProductName from TableName  where id = " & id)

 Do Until objRS.EOF
if (objRS("ProductName") and objRS("PurchaseDate")  <= dateadd(day,-90,getdate())) and objRS("ProductName") and isNull(objRS("PurchaseDate")) then
    AlreadyPurchased = true
end if
objRS.movenext()
Loop
```

My loop that writes it to the page:

```
<%=objrs("ProductName")%><% if AlreadyPurchased then%>Last Purchased     with     last 90 days<%end if %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best answer depends on a few assumptions:

A) your query does not return any NULL values, and

B) that you have previously stored the product name in a preexisting variable.

Your code has some issues.

1)  `if (objRS("ProductName")` is basically asking if the fieldset value is a `True` boolean value.  My first assumption is that you already know the product name that you're testing.  So, the above snippet should be replaced with this: `if (objRS("ProductName").value = strMyProductName` where `strMyProductName` is a variable that stores the product name (as a string).

2) You should consider storing the calculated date in a variable outside the loop.  No need to repeatedly compute the date if you can compute it once, store it in a variable, and use the variable in your comparison.

3) Remove the last component of your conditional `and objRS("ProductName")` because it's redundant and has the same faulty logic as what I explained in (1) above.

4) Your `DateAdd()` can be written better.

TL;DR

```
dim strMyProductName, dat90, AlreadyPurchased

AlreadyPurchased = false

strMyProductName = "Shoes"

dat90 = dateadd("d", -90, now) '90 days ago

Do Until objRS.EOF
    if cstr(objRS("ProductName").value)=strMyProductName and cdate(objRS("PurchaseDate")) <= dat90 then
        AlreadyPurchased = true
        exit do
    end if
    objRS.movenext()
Loop
```

Comment: Actually, I don't know the product name. I just want to tag the product name with "AlreadyPurchased" if already purchased within 90 days. So better explaining, that will probably alter your code. Thanks

Comment: OK.  Can you update your original question with the query you're executing?  That'll help me fine tune my answer.

Comment: The query that I am executing hasn't changed but obviously not working and I was doubting if I was even on the correct path. The question is pretty much the same. To slightly restate the question - if I have a user that selects a product that is already in their account that they purchased 90 days or less ago, I want to notify them that it is a duplicate purchase. I don't want to stop the duplicate purchase, I just want to as a curtsey, let them know that it is a duplicate within that 90 day period.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect a good bit of your code.  Code runs without error but no results - so missing something.

Comment: The code I provided was based an assumption that proved false.  I need you to update your original post with the query you executed to get the result set.

Comment: Ok, my original code posted, but I wasn't getting any results at all. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: and I think my code that writes the info to the page is correct; it's just not the correct code to being it there.

Comment: No, I need the SQL query that is producing objRS -- look through your script for it and paste that into your code.

Comment: edited post - It's a bit more complicated SQL than that, using joins etc, and working fine for years.  I reduced it to simplicity for this purpose of trying to figure the VB code so I can flag duplicates.